# Diferenciar valores de una columna según agrupaciones de otra en R

Tags: r, dataframe, rstudio, datos

Quisiera poder resolver la siguiente casuística, tengo un dataframe con 8 niveles jerárquicos y ocurre lo siguiente, les dejo un ejemplo:

```r
> id1=c(rep("GRUPO_FUM",4),rep("GRUPO_FLM",4),"GRUPO3_FLN","GRUPO4_FLK")
> id2=c(rep("SGRUPO",10))
> df1<-data.frame(id1,id2)
> df1
          id1    id2
1   GRUPO_FUM SGRUPO
2   GRUPO_FUM SGRUPO
3   GRUPO_FUM SGRUPO
4   GRUPO_FUM SGRUPO
5   GRUPO_FLM SGRUPO
6   GRUPO_FLM SGRUPO
7   GRUPO_FLM SGRUPO
8   GRUPO_FLM SGRUPO
9  GRUPO3_FLN SGRUPO
10 GRUPO4_FLK SGRUPO
```

Me gustaría que para grupos diferentes las cadenas de la segunda columna también se diferencien por alguna letra o número:

```
          id1    id2
1   GRUPO_FUM SGRUPO_1
2   GRUPO_FUM SGRUPO_1
3   GRUPO_FUM SGRUPO_1
4   GRUPO_FUM SGRUPO_1
5   GRUPO_FLM SGRUPO_2
6   GRUPO_FLM SGRUPO_2
7   GRUPO_FLM SGRUPO_2
8   GRUPO_FLM SGRUPO_2
9  GRUPO3_FLN SGRUPO_3
10 GRUPO4_FLK SGRUPO_4
```

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con R base puedes armar algo como esto:

```
df1$new_id2 <- with(df1,
     paste0(id2, "_", as.numeric(factor(id1, levels = unique(df1$id1))))
)

df1

         id1    id2  new_id2
1   GRUPO_FUM SGRUPO SGRUPO_1
2   GRUPO_FUM SGRUPO SGRUPO_1
3   GRUPO_FUM SGRUPO SGRUPO_1
4   GRUPO_FUM SGRUPO SGRUPO_1
5   GRUPO_FLM SGRUPO SGRUPO_2
6   GRUPO_FLM SGRUPO SGRUPO_2
7   GRUPO_FLM SGRUPO SGRUPO_2
8   GRUPO_FLM SGRUPO SGRUPO_2
9  GRUPO3_FLN SGRUPO SGRUPO_3
10 GRUPO4_FLK SGRUPO SGRUPO_4
```

Transformamos el `id2` en un `factor` y al convertirlo en un numérico obtenemos el índice de cada grupo.

Comment: Gracias @PatricioMoracho tu respuesta es útil para mi, no había pensado en convertir a factor y luego a numérico para obtener los índices.